# Jabber ID (XMPP JID) on own domain

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp

Instead of app-id@appspot.com or any@app-id.appspot.com I would like to use
any@own-domain.tld.

can this be one when using app-engine xmpp service, 
when own-domain is using google apps for mail service

This would be a great option if available.

We feel many getting worried to add when they find @appspot.com at end,
also when they see an app id which may not much same as our domain name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately App Engine doesn't support this feature yet.

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2145